# Javascript syntax error identified 'for' keyword

Tags: javascript, web-applications, syntax-error

This is my Javascript function:

```
function newgame()
{
    var status = document.getElementById('status');

    xTurn = true;
    status.innerHTML = 'X\'s turn';

    for(var x ==0; x < x++) {
        for(var y ==0; y < y++) {
            document.getElementById(x + '_' + y).value = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Error is identified at line `for(var x ==0; x < x++)    {`

Please help me find what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax of for loop

```
for (var i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
{
document.write(cars[i] + "<br>");
}
```

You can't use `==` here.You need to use `=` sign here.
 `==` compare the values and `=` is for assignment.Also your second condition is also missing in lop so It is a invalid loop statement.
I think your desired loop could be like this

```
for(var x =0; x <(where you want to terminate) ;x++) {
        for(var y =0; y < (where you want to terminate) ; y++) {
         document.getElementById(x + '_' + y).value = ' ';
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` is an equality check. You can't use it when you create a variable with `var` (and it looks like you are trying to *assign* `0` which would use `=`

Answer (score 0):

You need also a second ; sign in the loop header. This is valid javascript syntax:

```
  for(var x = x==0; x < x++;)    {
     for(var y = y==0; y < y++;)       {
        document.getElementById(x + '_' + y).value = ' ';
     }
  }
```

But it does only set x to 1 and not much more, because `x < x++` is always false.